# Monthly average precipitation calculation from a GPM precipitation ImageCollection?

Tags: google-earth-engine, gpm

I want to extract the precipitation from a Image Collection and make a chart of the temporal variation of the precipitation. Can I take a single or a weighted mean of the geometry? How can I calculate the monthly precipitation? I tried following piece of code but I'm doing something wrong. How could I improve it?

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GPM_L3/IMERG_MONTHLY_V06')
    .filterDate('2000', '2020');
// Select the mean precipitation values.
var precipitation = dataset.select('precipitation').mean().clip(table);
var mask = precipitation.gt(0.0);
var precipitation = precipitation.updateMask(mask);

//Calcular la Precipitación mensual
var addMonthlyPrecip = function (precipitation) {
  var start = ee.Date(precipitation.get('system:time_start'));
  var end = start.advance(1, 'month');
  var hoursInMonth = end.difference(start, 'hours');
  return precipitation.addBands(precipitation.multiply(hoursInMonth).rename('precip_mm_month'));
};
var ic = dataset.map(addMonthlyPrecip);

Map.addLayer(ic, {bands:'precip_mm_month', max: 720});

//Darle colores al mapa
var palette = [ 
  '000096','0064ff', '00b4ff', '33db80', '9beb4a',
  'ffeb00', 'ffb300', 'ff6400', 'eb1e00', 'af0000'
];

//Plotea la media de la región
var stats = precipitation.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  geometry: table,
  scale: 10000,
  })
print(stats.get('precipitation'))

//Imprime el numero de imagenes que se estan operando
var precipitationVis = {min: 0.0, max: 1.5, palette: palette};
//Map.addLayer(clipped05, colorizedVis, 'NDVI');
//Define the chart and print it to the console.
Map.addLayer(precipitation, precipitationVis, 'Precipitation');
Map.setCenter(-66.6, 1.67, 6);
//Crear grafico imageCollection(serie de tiempo)
var chart =
    ui.Chart.image.series(dataset.select('precipitation'), table, ee.Reducer.mean(), 500,'system:time_start')
        .setSeriesNames(['precipitacion'])
        .setOptions({
          title: 'Average Precipitation',
          hAxis: {title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
          vAxis: {
            title: 'precipitation (mm/h)',
            titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
          },
          lineWidth: 5,
          colors: ['e37d05', '1d6b99'],
          curveType: 'function'
        });
print(chart);
```

This is the link:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/71b2c0ffc4ead42aefd1d769ae7b86f6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that kind of function in your script because is a already monthly product. However, as units in each band of precipitation are mm/hr, you have two options. One approximated assuming all months have 30 days or one more exact considering days per month (also taking in account leap years). I chose second option.

Following [script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/22c62246c05fa8b2310e501c5b3a29b9) has a function for multiplying each monthly values (mm/day) by month days; taking in account leap years (28 or 29 days for February). It also pairs these values with corresponding dates. I considered an arbitrary geometry (table) in USA. It looks as follows.

```
var startYear = '2001';
var endYear = '2020';

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GPM_L3/IMERG_MONTHLY_V06')
    .filterDate(startYear, endYear)
    .select('precipitation');
    
print(dataset);

var getPrecipit = function(image) {

  // Reducing region and getting value
  var value_ppt = ee.Image(image)
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), table)
    .get('precipitation');

  return ee.Number(value_ppt).multiply(24);  //mm/day

};

var count = dataset.size();

var ppt_list = dataset.toList(count).map(getPrecipit);

print("ppt_list (mm/day)", ppt_list);

var year_list = ee.List.sequence(ee.Number.parse(startYear), ee.Number.parse(endYear).subtract(1));

var leapYear_list = year_list.map( function leapYear(year) {
  
  return ee.Number(year).mod(4).eq(0).and(ee.Number(year).mod(100).neq(0)).or(ee.Number(year).mod(400).eq(0));
  
});

//print(leapYear_list);

var monthNumberDays = leapYear_list.map(function (ele) {

  return ee.Algorithms
    .If(ee.Number(ele).eq(1), [31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31], 
                              [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]);
  
}).flatten();

//print("Month Number Days", monthNumberDays);

var monthlyValues = ppt_list.map(function (ele){
  
  var idx = ppt_list.indexOf(ele);
  
  return ee.Number(ele).multiply(monthNumberDays.get(idx));
  
});

//print(monthlyValues);

var allDates = ee.List(dataset.aggregate_array('system:time_start'));

var allDatesSimple = allDates.map(function(date){
  return ee.Date(date).format().slice(0,7);
  });

//print(allDatesSimple);

var paired = allDatesSimple.zip(monthlyValues);

print("ppt_list (mm/month)", paired);

var myFeatures = ee.FeatureCollection(paired.map(function(el){
  el = ee.List(el); // cast every element of the list
  return ee.Feature(null, {
    'date': ee.String(el.get(0)),
    'ppt_monthly':ee.Number(el.get(1))
  });
}));

//print(myFeatures);

// Export features, specifying corresponding names.
Export.table.toDrive(myFeatures,
"export_ppt", //my task
"GEE_Folder", //my export folder
"ppt_monthly",  //file name
"CSV");
```

After running it in GEE code editor, I got result of following image; where it can be observed paired dates and monthly values in Console Tab.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, with what function can I export the values ​​that the code throws to csv??

Comment: You're welcome. I edited my script for including corresponding lines to export paired values as CSV file.

Comment: I tried to show the raster in the viewer but the variables I think are like lists, you know how I could do it to have a graphical output of my data?
var palette = [ 
  '000096','0064ff', '00b4ff', '33db80', '9beb4a',
  'ffeb00', 'ffb300', 'ff6400', 'eb1e00', 'af0000']

var precipitationVis = {min: 0.0, max: 500, palette: palette};

//Define the chart and print it to the console.
Map.addLayer(getPrecipit, precipitationVis, 'Precipitation');
Map.setCenter(-66.6, 1.67, 6);

Answer (score 0):

This is a more concise way of calculating the monthly precipitation based on hourly precipitation.
Main difference with xunilk's answer, is that I use the 'knowledge' of GEE about dates in a function to calculate the amount of days per month.
Method is inspired by a python post using datetime module I saw a long time ago.

If you get the current month and advance to the next month. Then move to the first day of that month and move 1 day to the past, you will end up on the last day of the current month, that value is of course the amount days in the current month.

[Link to script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/b113d98b169d66c56606c8a7627bf4f2)

```js
    var startYear = '2001';
    var endYear = '2020';
    
    var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/GPM_L3/IMERG_MONTHLY_V06')
        .filterDate(startYear, endYear)
        .select('precipitation');
    
    // arbitrary geometry
    var geometry = ee.Geometry.Point([144.034676,-11.5905186]).buffer(5000)
    
    // Function looks difficult, but it's just a bit messy
    // It accepts a date as input and performs the following steps:
    // 1. Constructs a new ee.Date using the year and month of the input date.
    //    Earth Engine interprets this as [year]-[month]-01.
    // 2. Advances the date to the next month.
    // 3. Moves back 1 day to reach the last day of the current month.
    // As a result, we obtain the number of days in the current month.
    var getDaysOfMonth = function(date){
      var next_mo = ee.Date(ee.String(date.get('year')).cat('-')
       .cat(ee.String(date.get('month'))))
      .advance(1, 'month')
      return next_mo.advance(-1, 'day' ).get('day')
    }
    
    var getPrecipit = function(image) {
      // get days of month of image
      var daysOfMonth = getDaysOfMonth(image.date());
      // Reducing region and getting value
      var value_ppt = image
        .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), geometry)
        .getNumber('precipitation')
        .multiply(24)
        .multiply(daysOfMonth);
     //return a feature with geometry null and these properties
      return ee.Feature(null, {
        'precipitation': value_ppt,
        'system:time_start': image.date(),
        'days_of_month':daysOfMonth
      })
    };
    
    var pptCol = dataset.map(getPrecipit);
    print(pptCol)
    
    print(ui.Chart.feature.byFeature({
      features: pptCol,
      xProperty: 'system:time_start',
      yProperties: ['precipitation']
    }))
    
    Map.centerObject(geometry, 13)
    Map.addLayer(geometry)
```

[image]